# Is a Join Faster than two queries

Tags: sql, performance, networking

I know this question has been asked before, 
[example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758712/which-of-the-following-sql-queries-would-be-faster-a-join-on-two-tables-or-succe), and I do agree that one query with a join is faster than performing another query for each record returned by the firs query.

However, since with a join you tend to generate redundant field will this slow the network ?

Let's say I have a table hotel and HOTEL has a number of images in a table HOTEL_IMAGE. HOTEL has 20 fields. performing a join on HOTEL_IMAGE will produce 20 fields for each hotel image. will this query still be faster over the network ?

Comment: Cop out - it depends :). Do you mean inner or outer joins (outer are far less efficient)? What RDBMS are you using? Are you joining on remote tables? Generally, joins will be faster but with many exceptions. Best thing to do is to check out the query plan for each in your situation.

Comment: @David - Correct answer though!

Comment: INNER JOIN and MYSql although I usually use MS SQL Server

Comment: In SQL Server you also have the option of bringing back as XML so the data is a tree rather than rectangular and you wouldn't get the repeated data from `HOTEL` Obviously that in itself would incur overhead though.

Comment: The join does not automatically produce 20 "fields" as long you only select the columns that you want.

Comment: Yes and we need the other fields ... I only use * for testing even if I know I need all the fields

Comment: @Jonny: Then I don't get the question. If *do* need the columns (and purposely select them) then a second statement would also need to select them. So what exactly is the question then?

Comment: @horse I do need them but only once. Using a join the hotel data will be returned for every image the hotel has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends **a lot** on your actual data, but from what I have seen, if you have a well-parameterized DB with fresh statistics, it is much better to put the join in SQL and let the DB figure out what to do.

Anyway, DB queries are in my opinion the first things you want to profile. It is not a coincidence that any good DBMS has a lot of performance measuring tools. And you need to profile with data as close to actual data as possible (recent copies of your production environment are best).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use select * but only the columns that you need. IF you do this, a join will be faster (not sure why you would ever want to do this with 2 queries, you have to make 2 connections to your database ect.)

Comment: Nowhere does the question mention `*`

Comment: Mine was just an example. Quite hard to explain in writing without writing a whole essay

Comment: @Martin Smith: "*will produce 20 fields*" sounds very much like `SELECT *` is being used.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - The gist of the question is clearly that if you are doing a join on a one to many relationship and the selected column list on the one side has large (BLOB) columns will the overhead of duplicating these outweigh the benefit of doing it in one query. There is no reason to conclude they are using `*` at all. Their application may need this data.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution to avoid duplication in joined data, you can return multiple recordsets from single query, if your database supports it. One recordset will return the master records, and second - the detail records plus the key fields from master query.

```
select ID, Name, ...  from HOTEL where <.... your criteria>;

select h.ID as HotelID, i.ID, i.Description, i.ImageFile, .... from HOTEL_IMAGE i 
join HOTEL h on h.ID = i.HotelID and ( <.... same criteria for HOTEL> )
```

Not sure if the query on the master table would be cached, so the second select will reuse it, but it will save traffic for sure.

We are using this approach for queries, which tend to return multi-level joined results.